# How to define multiple type of comment block in Parsec

Tags: delphi, haskell, parsec

I am trying to learn how to use `Parsec` to write a Delphi parser, but I am getting stuck at defining the LanguageDef.

In Delphi, there are two types of comment blocks, `(* comments *)` and `{ comments }`.
But the types of commentStart & commentEnd of LanguageDef are String, not [String], so I could only put in one or the other.

So, I tried to make my own whiteSpace parser, but I'm not sure I could actually pass it into `makeTokenParser`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

---

John and Chris have helped me to understand and get around the problem, but the solution involves replacing a huge number of parsers that `makeTokenParser` provides, so it's not exactly desirable.

I will post again if I could find a better solution.

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but Mike Lischke made an open source delphi parser and lexer, known as [DCC](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=25&Itemid=33).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My reading of the `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Language` file is that this cannot be done directly using a `LanguageDef`.

I believe you are on the right track to write your own `whiteSpace` parser.  In order to use it successfully, you need to overwrite the `whiteSpace` parser that is generated by `makeTokenParser`.  The `TokenParser` created by `makeTokenParser` is a record with each field containing a parser.  We can create a new copy of the record with one of those fields replaced as follows:

```
-- ask GCHi for the type actual type signature constraints
-- Type sig is approx. fixWhiteSpace :: TokenParser -> Parser -> TokenParser
fixWhiteSpace originalTokenParser myWhiteSpaceParser = 
  originalTokenParser {whiteSpace = myWhiteSpaceParser}
```

Comment: I had a quick try, it didn't seem to work, but I could be doing something else wrong. I'll spend a bit more time on it.

Just to confirm, if there is another parser in the `originalTokenParser` which is defined with the original `whiteSpace`, would this parser automatically use `myWhiteSpaceParser` once I have applied `fixWhiteSpace`?

Comment: @epak: No.  All the values are immutable, so defining "newParser = fixWhiteSpace blach" does not affect originalTokenParser.

Comment: @ChrisKuklewicz: Thanks for clearing that up for me and in fact that is the underlying problem. The `lexeme` parser is defined in terms of `whiteSpace` and a whole lot more parsers, including `identifier`, are defined in terms of `lexeme`. Once I have replaced the `identifier` parser with my definition of `lexeme` and `whiteSpace` like @John suggested, it would handle multiple types of comment blocks.